# Installing gnuplot from MacPorts failed (Checksum Mismacth)

Tags: macos, macports, gnuplot

I have OSX 10.5 and tried to `sudo port install gnuplot`, only to get this:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for gnuplot
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for gnuplot
Error: Checksum (md5) mismatch for gnuplot.pdf
Error: Checksum (sha1) mismatch for gnuplot.pdf
Error: Checksum (rmd160) mismatch for gnuplot.pdf
```

I don't care whether gnuplot.pdf has a checksum mismatch, it's not part of the executables... how do I get around this? I can't seem to re-download or uninstall either.

Comment: See [the MacPorts FAQ](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#checksums) for some steps and notes about checksum mismatches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did

```
sudo port -d selfupdate
sudo port clean gnuplot
sudo port install gnuplot
```

and that fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

1. First try @Jason's solution - updating that specific port may do the trick.
2. Do a little bit of googling to understand why the checksum is failing.

The macports wiki lists [common reasons for checksum failure](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#checksums) and (in my personal experience) it is often a stealth upgrade by an upstream developer ([like this one](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/50337)).  If you have confirmed the cause of the checksum failure is benign you can override the macport checksum like this:

`sudo port install gnuplot checksum.skip=yes`